# como mostrar un reporte Reportlab en el navegador?

Tags: python, django, reportlab

Soy nueva con reportlab, el problema que tengo es que apesar de poder crear reportes con reportlab, sólo los he podido guardar en la carpeta raiz de mi proyecto, pero al subirlo a un servidor de prueba me sale este error:

#### Error y Traceback

```
IOError at /PHVA/pdfJornadas
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'Reporte Jornadas de Trabajo Cliente 1 S.A.S.pdf'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://cliente1.mydomain.com/PHVA/pdfJornadas
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'Reporte Jornadas de Trabajo Cliente 1 S.A.S.pdf'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py in SaveToFile, line 218
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/var/www/html/cliente1/my_project']
Server time:    Jue, 10 Mar 2016 09:46:10 -0500  


Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
/var/www/html/cliente1/my_project/phva/views/reportes.py in exportarJornadasTrabajo
    doc.build(Story) ...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py in build
        BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker) ...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py in build
        self._endBuild() ...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py in _endBuild
        if getattr(self,'_doSave',1): self.canv.save() ...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py in save
        self._doc.SaveToFile(self._filename, self) ...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py in SaveToFile
            f = open(filename, "wb") ...
```

#### parte de mi views (Actualizado)

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse

#from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Table, TableStyle, Image

from phva.forms import *
from matriz_legal.models import *
from gestion_riesgos.models import *
from capacitaciones.models import MatrizFormacion
from ripso.utilities import *

def exportarJornadasTrabajo(request):
    empresa=PlanearEmpresa.objects.all()[0]
    title = "Reporte Jornadas de Trabajo "+empresa.razon_social
    filename = title+".pdf"
    # Creamos el response
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
    # Usando el response en lugar del filename
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response,pagesize=letter, rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72, topMargin=72,bottomMargin=18)
    Story=[]

    #...

    #Jornadas
    jornadas=PlanearJornadaTrabajo.objects.all().order_by('grupo')

    if jornadas:
        datos_jorn=[]
        datos_jorn.append(['Grupo', 'Nombre', 'Horario'])
        for i in jornadas:
            datos_jorn.append([i.get_grupo_display(), Paragraph(i.nombre, styles['Justify']), Paragraph(i.horario, styles['Justify'])])
        t=Table(datos_jorn, colWidths=(4*cm, 4*cm, 8*cm))
        t.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(-1,0),colors.gray),
                               ('GRID', (0,1), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.gray)]))
        Story.append(t)
        Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
    else:
        p=ParagraphStyle('test')
        ptext = '<font size=12>No se encuentran datos disponibles registrados.</font>'
        Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, p))
        Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))

    #...

    doc.build(Story)
    return response
```

#### Actualizado

El método del views se me está ejecutando 2 veces al cambiarlo a return response

Comment: Diana, ¿puedes poner el traceback completo?, ¿la ruta `/PHVA/pdfJornadas` corresponde a la vista `exportarAusentismos`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es enviar el flujo de información del PDF hacia el cliente para su descarga lo que tienes que hacer es retornar un [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse).

Ejemplo:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def exportarJornadasTrabajo(request):
    empresa = PlanearEmpresa.objects.all()[0]
    filename = "Reporte Jornadas de Trabajo %s.pdf" % empresa.razon_social
    # Creamos el response
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
    # Observa que ahora en vez de usar el nombre del archivo usamos el response
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
        response,
        pagesize=letter, 
        rightMargin=72,
        leftMargin=72, 
        topMargin=72,
        bottomMargin=18
    )
    Story=[]
    # ...
    doc.build(Story) 
    # En vez de retornar un redirect retornamos el response
    return response
```

Comment: me puedes ayudar en algo más? y si quiero abrir el response en otra pestaña? sólo con target="_blank" en el template?

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez el tema es que si quieres usar el PDF en algún enlace `<a href="" ..>` tendrías que tener el archivo guardado en tu servidor

Comment: mira, tengo un problema con la forma en la que estoy haciendo el reporte,  creo que tu respuesta viene de [https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/] (para el proyecto que estoy probando uso django 1.6.5) lo que me pasa a mí es que si genero el pdf sin el response se ejecuta el método del views una sola vez, pero no entiendo porqué al generar el pdf con el response se me está ejecutando 2 veces el método correspondiente.

Comment: por favor explícame lo que dices de la etiqueta a... porque lo que yo tengo son botones de tipo <a href="{% url 'crear_pdf_redirect' %}" target="_blank"> <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right"> PDF redirect </button> </a> y no pasa nada incorrecto.

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez si los estás usando para descargar directamente entonces es correcto lo que estás haciendo porque simplemente estás llamando a la función, me refería a que si quieres mostrar el PDF al usuario "antes de", en ese caso te decía que tendrías que tener el PDF guardado por algún lado

Comment: mi idea inicial era que al dar clic en el botón, se llevara a otra página para mostrarlo y luego el usuario decida descargarlo o no (lo que decías de ..  mostrar el PDF al usuario "antes de")

pero como lo tengo me ejecuta el método 2 veces.... o cómo hago para que cuando el usuario dé clic en el botón directamente se le descargue el pdf sin mostrarlo antes? (eso también me sirve)

Answer (score 0):

Tengo algo parecido a lo que pides,

éste es mi código HTML en un Template de Django y hago un POST a una URL que me recibe el parámetro que le envio aca

```
<div class="cuerpo"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="width: auto;">
            <div class="panel-heading">Reporte Stock Productos por Almacen</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form form-horizontal" id='contra' name='contra' method='post' action='http://localhost:8000/reportestockalmacen/'>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cmbalmacen" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label">Almacen</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                                 <select class="form-control" name="cmbalmacen" id="cmbalmacen" required style="width:50%">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-4">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>                                
                                <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Aceptar"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                        

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

y este vendría a ser mi código Python que además el método se tiene que agregar a la URL.

```
def ReporteStockAlmacen(request):

if request.method == 'POST':        

    try:

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='ReporteProductosAlamcen/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Reporte_Productos_Almacen.pdf"'

        almacen=request.POST['cmbalmacen']                      
        jsonfinal = Get_ProductosPorAlmacen(almacen)

        data2 = jsonfinal["almacen"]

        temp = StringIO()
        width, height = A4
        p = canvas.Canvas(temp,pagesize = A4)   
        xPos = 50
        yPos = 685
        aum = 15
        pie = 60
        fecha = timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        p.setFont("Helvetica",8)
        p.drawString(230, 730, "STOCK DE PRODUCTOS")
        p.drawString(215, 715, "Reporte generado el  "+str(fecha))
        p.line(700, 700, 0, 700)#(HORIZONTAL,,HORIZONTAL,)
        p.drawString(xPos, yPos, "CODIGO")
        p.drawString(xPos+120, yPos, "PRODUCTO")
        p.drawString(xPos+360, yPos, "SERIE")

        p.line(700, yPos-5, 0, yPos-5)                          

        for almacen in data2:

            p.drawString(500, 715, almacen['nombrealmacen'])

            if(yPos <= pie):
                p.showPage()
                p.save()
                xPos = 50
                yPos = 780
                aum = 15    
            x=0

            for productos in almacen["productos"]:
                p.setFont("Helvetica",8)

                if x == 0:
                    p.drawString(xPos, yPos-aum,productos['codigoproducto'])
                    p.drawString(xPos+120, yPos-aum,productos['nombreproducto'])
                    p.drawString(xPos+360, yPos-aum,productos['serieproducto_almacens'])
                    yPos-=aum


                    p.setFont("Helvetica",8)
                    if(yPos <= pie):

                        p.showPage()
                        p.save()

                        xPos = 50                       
                        yPos = 780
                        aum = 15                

        p.showPage()
        p.save()
        response.write(temp.getvalue())


        return response
    except:
        HttpResponse({'exito':0})
```